# Include variable string inside JS function (HTA app)

Tags: javascript, variables, hta

I am trying to include variable inside `cmd /c runas` command, I use JS function and it gives me an error that specified file was not found.

I guess I am using the wrong variable calling or something.

Here is my function:

```
function runasSRVhta(){
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
// var srvDude = document.getElementById("SRVinput").value;
var SRVguy = "someadmin.srv";
WShell.Run('cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\\SRVguy "c:\\windows\\system32\\mshta.exe """\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\giveMeIPsPLZ.hta""""', 1, true);
}
```

Instead of running following command as someadmin.srv it runs its variable name, without taking value.

Problem is here - `cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\\SRVguy`, SRVguy should be variable taken from var `SRVguy = "someadmin.srv";`

- **Update**

I tried following function as well, it detects variable value, but my HTA gives me another error saying that it can't find the file specified.

```
function testsrv() {
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var SRVguy = "someadmin.srv";
  var SRVguyaftertext = 'c:\\windows\\system32\\mshta.exe """\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\giveMeIPsPLZ.hta"""';
  var satavesrv = 'cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\\';
  var theend = "'" + satavesrv + SRVguy + ' "' + SRVguyaftertext + '"' + "'";
  document.write(theend);
  var path = theend;
  shell.run(theend,1,false);
}
```

Oh, and I used document.write to check output if it is correct, here is the output:

```
'cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\someadmin.srv "c:\windows\system32\mshta.exe """\\fs\FIle Share\SA Support\ZverTools\giveMeIPsPLZ.hta""""'
```

Everything seems correct with second function, but HTA pops up an error message saying that it cannot find the file specified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using template strings to include the variable in the string like this

```
WShell.Run(`cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\\${SRVguy} "c:\\windows\\system32\\mshta.exe """\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\giveMeIPsPLZ.hta""""`, 1, true);
```

**- Update**

```
WShell.Run('cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\\' +SRVguy + ' "c:\\windows\\system32\\mshta.exe """\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\giveMeIPsPLZ.hta"""', 1, true);
```

Comment: Gave me an error saying invalid character, I think it considers `` as an invalid character

Comment: try this then WShell.Run('cmd /c runas /u:sa.local\\' +SRVguy + ' "c:\\windows\\system32\\mshta.exe """\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\giveMeIPsPLZ.hta"""', 1, true);

Comment: Works like a charm, submit your comment as an answer and I will mark it as a solution.